# Using the same app name for phone and tablet

Tags: ios, google-play

We have two versions of our app on the iTunes and Google Play store (2 on iTunes and 2 on Google Play).  One for phone and one for tablet.  These are separate apps with different code bases.

Right now they are named such as APPNAME and APPNAME TABLET, however, we would like both to use the same name.  How can we make them both named the same in the app store?

Let us know if additional clarification is needed.

Thank you!

P.S. When we initial tried to use the same name, we get error such as "The Application Name that you provided has already been used. Please provide a unique Application Name."

Comment: The error you mentioned must be from iTunes because I don't think there is any such restriction on PlayStore.

Comment: On Play you'd either use a single apk, or a single app with multiple apks. You wouldn't use two different apps.

Comment: Thank you for the quick replies. Google Play store is definitely more flexible in term of naming.  Although we found "Creating multiple APKs for your application is not the normal procedure for publishing an application on Google Play." language from google.

And yes, that particular error is from iTunes.

Comment: For anyone looking for multiple apks info on Google Play: https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html

Comment: Is there a reason for downvote? We'll be happy to provide additional clarification.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I hope we are not confusing package name of the application with App name here, as play store won't allow you to upload two applications with same package name.

Two apps can have same name (Title) on Google playstore though, it's just you will end up confuse the user which one to download and you will end up having bad reviews.

You may use `<supports-screens />` in your manifest file to specifically let playstore know which app it will show to the user depending on screen-size.

Lastly, why have different code bases for tablet and mobile if they share the same java code, just add the `res` in the mobile app. Android is smart enough to pick resources based on device density.

Comment: Yeah, package name are different from just app title.  As you mentioned, it is our understanding as well that package name cannot be same, but that is currently lower priority for us at this point.

Comment: Initially we have the phone app, and the tablet app came later. When first developing the tablet app, it was understood due to the different functionalities and layout from the phone app, we will have two code base and thus two apps.  But requirement is now changed, and we want to have one app, or at least apps with same name.  Hope this clarifies.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider **Multiple APK Support** feature in Google Play dev console: https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html

> Multiple APK support is a feature on Google Play that allows you to
>   publish different APKs for your application that are each targeted to
>   different device configurations. Each APK is a complete and
>   independent version of your application, but they share the same
>   application listing on Google Play and must share the same package
>   name and be signed with the same release key. This feature is useful
>   for cases in which your application cannot reach all desired devices
>   with a single APK.

You probably can use there filters for screen size and density, to target tablets.

As for iOS devices, seems that it doesn't support such approach

Comment: Thank you.  Yeah, we have added the multiple-apks info for Google Play in the comment section of the question. And yeah, still looking for iOS approach.